# Can't create sbt addCommandAlias to skip tests and just do clean assembly

Tags: sbt, syntax-error

I am working on a old sbt 0.13.12 project and want to create an alias for the command:

```
$sbt "set test in Test := {}" clean assembly
```

I have tried the following below, which all fail with either because of:  usage, No valid parser available, or ')' expected but ';' found errors.

```
addCommandAlias("ca", "\"set test in Test := {}\" clean assembly")
addCommandAlias("ca", "\"set test in Test := {}\"; clean; assembly;")
addCommandAlias("ca", ";\"set test in Test := {}\"; clean; assembly")
addCommandAlias("ca", ";"set test in Test := {}"; clean; assembly")
addCommandAlias("ca", ";set test in Test := {}; clean; assembly")
addCommandAlias("ca", ';"set test in Test := {}"; clean; assembly')
```

All the examples I have read do not have an argument that has spaces, so it might not be possible to create this type of alias, but you would think it would be supported somehow.

So has anyone successfully create this type of alias?